# When I add jQuery library it invalidates my other jQuery on the same page

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to create a page that has a scroller of images and a voting system (which I copied from here: http://yensdesign.com/2008/09/how-to-create-a-stunning-and-smooth-popup-using-jquery/).

The scroller was working just fine until I added the voting pop-up. Essentially, when I add the library

```
<script src="http://jqueryjs.googlecode.com/files/jquery-1.2.6.min.js" type="text/javascript">
```

needed for the pop-up to work, the scroller images disappear and the page seems to re-load whenever I hit the scrolling arrows. If I comment out the library above then the scroller re-appears (but the pop-up window does not work). Here are the directories for the other files.

- public/scripts/general0.js - init for scroller
- public/script/woo-jcar.js - scroller function
- public/scripts/popup.js" - pop-up javascript

Please Help!  I am a newby so this might just be a dumb thing like adding to conflicting libraries or something.

Thanks,

Comment: that's a kinda old jquery version isn't it? Are you just adding 2 different jquery libs?

Comment: +1 for including a link to the actual site you're working on... this needs to happen more often here. :P

Comment: @SpikeX, I disagree; I find it hard to trust links to someone's site when they're in a development phase. They could become compromised, or simply be down. Additionally, any changes made while the question is being answered could lead to ambiguity. I'd much rather see a distilled version of the problem in [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net) so that everyone's on equal footing.

Comment: @zzzzBov This is true, however in lieu of jsFiddle I'd rather see a working site link than nothing at all. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

jQuery already exists on your page (version 1.7.1) on this line of your HTML markup:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="public/scripts/jquery00.js"></script>
```

Remove this line, and you should be fine:

```
<script src="http://jqueryjs.googlecode.com/files/jquery-1.2.6.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

Comment: If I remove:<!--<script src="http://jqueryjs.googlecode.com/files/jquery-1.2.6.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>--> then the pop-up does not appear when i hit "Vote".

Comment: Then the popup is not compatible with more recent versions of jQuery. I suggest you find another "popup" - here's a tip: they're called **[Lightboxes](http://google.com/search?q=lightbox+jquery)**.

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned by Rocket, use noConflict to turn $ back on 1.7.2 and reference jQuery 1.2.6 with $jq126:

```
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.2/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.2.6/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $jq126 = $.noConflict(true);
    // $ (and jQuery) is jQuery 1.7.2
    // $jq126 is jQuery 1.2.6
</script>
```

If that is not enough probably the pop-up library depends strictly on the jQuery 1.2.6. So then open the pop-up libray js file and wrap all the code in the fallowing way:

```
(function($, jQuery){
    // all the lib code
})($jq126, $jq126);
```

In this way the old lib continues to reference the old version of jQuery.